# Spring Boot, MongoDB connection timeout

Tags: mongodb, azure, spring-boot, java-8

I have following problem:
 1. I have setup spring boot app which uses MongoDB database.
 2. I tested it locally and it works - app connects to database properly.
 3. I deployed spring boot app to azure, but app cannot connect to MongoDB database. I get below exception:

> "Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for a server that matches     ReadPreferenceServerSelector{readPreference=primary}. Client view of     cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=    [{address=appexpirer.documents.azure.com:10250, type=UNKNOWN,     state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadTimeoutException:     Timeout while receiving message}, caused by     {java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out}}]; nested exception is      com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException:
>   Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for a server that matches     ReadPreferenceServerSelector{readPreference=primary}. Client view of     cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=    [{address=appexpirer.documents.azure.com:10250, type=UNKNOWN,     state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadTimeoutException:     Timeout while receiving message}, caused by     {java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out}}]"

I believe that my application.properties are properly configured:

> spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://username:password@host:port/databaseName?ssl=true&sslInvalidHostNameAllowed=true
>   server.ssl.enabled=true
>   server.ssl.enabled-protocols=true

but I am not sure of that - could you please advice me what is wrong?

If I connect with using Robomongo tool everyting works well.
I use Java 8 - can it be problem?

Comment: How was the boot app deployed to azure? Is there anything that might be preventing outbound access to your DocumentDb endpoint?

Comment: I deployed app.jar file and web.config file via git. I wonder if it can be problem with ssl, because I have no ssl configured on app service on Azure and MongoDB requires SSL connection - have you ever met with such case?

Comment: I can hit mongo endpoint your error shows from a boot up from my machine. It shows authentication error (obviosly), so it seems like the the connectivity issue is not to the mongo endpoint, but rather from where your boot app lives.

Comment: I believe that azure app service need ssl certificate to communicate with mongodb, since the only way is to use ssl to connect to mongodb - I will try to investigate it more.

Comment: Finally I have solved it. The problem was really stupid. When I upload app.jar file via git app was in fact not updated on Azure. I noticed that there was exception which indicated that app cannot be updated, because previous version is running... I had to stop process manually, upload new version and then run uploaded version manually. Anyway thank you all for help.

Comment: Have you solved your problem? I have the same problem with you.

Answer (score 0):

Did you open up the connection from your app server to the database(Mongo) server?  That error sounds like a firewall just dropping the request packets.

Services like Azure and AWS have everything locked down pretty tightly.   You generally have to explicitly open up or allow every connection point you want to use.

Comment: What do you mean - "Did you open up the connection from your app server to the database(Mongo) server"? I have setup app service and database server. Both are setup and hosted on Azure. Should I somehow setup connection between those two on Azure? I can connect to database from Robomongo, but not from app service (always get timestamp).

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem for the Spring boot services deployed on AWS Beanstalk. The problem was occurring because I deployed new version and the old versions were still running on ECS.

I had to manually terminate the environment and deploy newly the services. IT resolved the issue. Only re-deployment without termination, does not help. Make sure to configure your Host / Domain to ELB again after new deployment.